# React Hooks: useHistory(), useParams(), useLocation() not updating simultanousely if used in multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use URL´s to enable some logic in order to show buttons. I am doing this by using the *useHistory, useLocation* and *useParams* hooks.

I use this hooks in each of my components (parent + child). I would expect that all of these hooks cause a rerender, when the URL changes.
**But it seems to be the case that each component remains at its own URL**. Which is quite confusing for me.

**Example**

---

**Description**:  *I have a parent and a child component. The parent component receives props, and based on the props it addes a hash to the current URL. Since the URL changed, the child component should be able to show the logic based on the change, as the useLocation should also update there.
**However** this is not the case. it is not updating.*

*Even if I pass the useHistory, pathname, or hash as props to the child component it is not working!*

Parent

```
const Parent= (props) => {

    const routeHistory = useHistory();
    const { pathname, hash } = useLocation();


    const updateHashRoute = () => {
        if (props.value == true) {
            routeHistory.push({ hash: '#apple' });
        } else {
            routeHistory.push({ hash: '#banana' });
        }
    }


    return (

        <div>
            <Child>

            </Child>



        </div>
    )
}
```

Child

```
const Child = () => {

    const routeHistory = useHistory();
    const { pathname, hash } = useLocation();

    const [buttonLogic, setButtonLogic] = useState({ showDecline: false, showAccept: false })

   useEffect(() => {
       decideButtonLogic()
   }, [hash])};

    // tree logic if accept/decline and back to hierarchy if detail logic
    const decideButtonLogic = () => {
        if (hash.includes('apple')) {
            setButtonLogic({ showDecline: false, showAccept: true })
        } else if (hash.includes('banana')) {
            setButtonLogic({ showDecline: true, showAccept: false })
        }
    }

    return (

        <div>
            { buttonLogic.showDecline && 
            <Button>
                Banana
            </Button>
            }
            { buttonLogic.showAccept && 
            <Button>
                Apple
            </Button>
            }



        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: how call `decideButtonLogic()`

Comment: @AshishKamble with useEffect. Sorry, forgot that.

Comment: have you wrapper Parent inside <Router>

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usehistory-useparams-uselocation-not-updating-simultanousel-snp2z) and from what I can tell it's working as you (*minimally*) describe. It's not clear what the issue is that you actually see. Can you create a *running* codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?